# Consuming ws security soap service in .Net Core 3 api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I am consuming a SOAP service in .NET Core 3.0 API. This service uses WS-Security standard for authentication. Will the below code work with just the username and password provided to the client credentials.

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _username;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;

Or the .NET Core service Model library does not support WS Security service?